# Enable fast startup in Windows 10 without affecting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

**Hi** I have a dualboot system on Asus X55C which has Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. So Ubuntu's performance is perfect but Windows takes very much time to boot and is very slow. So while installing Ubuntu I disabled fast startup from Windows because I saw peoples disabling it in many tutorials. So due to a very slow performance I want to turn it back on. So my question is that would it affect Ubuntu ? or mess with its grub loader. I saw some similar questions like this but they didn't have a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Technically* yes, but there are some important caveats you must be aware of:

If you share *any* partitions between Windows and Ubuntu, then any *writes* that you make to the Windows partition while it is in a "Fast Startup" shutdown state can result in data loss, as the partition is not in a "clean" state when the computer is shut down with this mode enabled.

However, if Ubuntu is configured only to read from the NTFS partition, then there is less risk of data loss or corruption. This can be configured in the `/etc/fstab` file by mounting the NTFS partition with the `ro` option.

You can find out more about [the options for `mount` via the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/mount.8.html) if you would like to share partitions between the two operating systems

Comment: I tried ```/etc/fstab``` as a comman user and also as a root and its giving me permission denied. And can you please give me another answer in detail that how it cause data corruptions between partitions because its confusing me so much ,Thankyou.@Matigo

Comment: `fstab` is a file. `sudo vi /etc/fstab` will allow you to examine it. As for more detail, it's simple: if you want to use "Fast Startup" with Windows, never, ever, *ever* write data to any Windows partition — especially the system partition (C:) — while you're using Ubuntu (or any other OS). Read. Don't write.

Comment: You were right @Matigo I enabled fast startup and my problem is solved now. I tried restarting from Ubuntu after shutdown in Windows and its boot is very fast now but what precautions should I take now to prevent data loss? Please reply me.Thankyou.

Comment: I will now only read data from C:drive and in case if I want to exchange data from this two OS I will first put it in the D:drive and then copy it because I use D:drive in both OS's. Any other precautions? @Matigo.